# Variable name from string and number in CMD FOR loop?

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I have a range of variables, which stores strings. These variables have index number that increments through FOR command.

I want to list all values from all these variables, which index numbers are generated from FOR definition (can be next time automated +1 or similar subfunction).

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set dir01a=text 1
set dir02a=text 2
set dir03a=text 3
for %G in (01 02 03) do (echo !dir%Ga!)
```

it outputs this:

```
!dir01a!
!dir02a!
!dir03a!
```

and I want this:

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
```

I cannot find any solution how to let the echo treat the `!dir%Ga!` like variable name and not text together.

Any idea please ?

If used in batch I would like to add one % more to the %G. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your batch script works:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set dir01a=text 1
set dir02a=text 2
set dir03a=text 3
for %%G in (01 02 03) do echo dir%%Ga =to= !dir%%Ga!
```

However, `SETLOCAL` command does not affect current `cmd` instance, you need to create new one, see `cmd /?` and update below.

- batch script: command pair `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and `ENDLOCAL`;
- command line: corresponding command pair `CMD /V:ON /K` and `EXIT` respectively.

**Copy & paste** next code snippet to an open `cmd` window:

```
ECHO OFF
set dir01a=text 1
set dir02a=text 2
set dir03a=text 3
for %G in (01 02 03) do echo dir%Ga =to= !dir%Ga!
cmd /E:ON /V:ON /C for %G in (01 02 03) do @echo dir%Ga =to= !dir%Ga!
ECHO ON >NUL
```

**Output**:

```
==> ECHO OFF
set dir01a=text 1
set dir02a=text 2
set dir03a=text 3
for %G in (01 02 03) do echo dir%Ga =to= !dir%Ga!
dir01a =to= !dir01a!
dir02a =to= !dir02a!
dir03a =to= !dir03a!
cmd /E:ON /V:ON /C for %G in (01 02 03) do @echo dir%Ga =to= !dir%Ga!
dir01a =to= text 1
dir02a =to= text 2
dir03a =to= text 3
ECHO ON >NUL
```

**Update: copy & paste** next code snippet **to an open `cmd` window** (note opportune `prompt` and `===` command prefix for better output readability):

```
prompt $Q$Q$G$S
echo OFF
=== set "var=OLD_value_d"
=== SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
=== set "var=NEW_value_d" & echo default expansion %var% !var! & set var
=== echo default expansion %var% !var!
=== ENDLOCAL
=== echo default expansion %var% !var!

=== CMD /V:ON /K
echo OFF
=== set "var=OLD_value_E"
=== set "var=NEW_value_E" & echo Delayed expansion %var% !var! & set var
=== echo Delayed expansion %var% !var!
=== EXIT

=== echo default expansion %var% !var!
=== echo ON >NUL
prompt
```

**Output**:

```
==> prompt $Q$Q$G$S

==> echo OFF
=== set "var=OLD_value_d"
=== SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
=== set "var=NEW_value_d" & echo default expansion %var% !var! & set var
default expansion OLD_value_d !var!
var=NEW_value_d
=== echo default expansion %var% !var!
default expansion NEW_value_d !var!
=== ENDLOCAL
=== echo default expansion %var% !var!
default expansion NEW_value_d !var!

=== CMD /V:ON /K
==> echo OFF
=== set "var=OLD_value_E"
=== set "var=NEW_value_E" & echo Delayed expansion %var% !var! & set var
Delayed expansion OLD_value_E NEW_value_E
var=NEW_value_E
=== echo Delayed expansion %var% !var!
Delayed expansion NEW_value_E NEW_value_E
=== EXIT

=== echo default expansion %var% !var!
default expansion NEW_value_d !var!
=== echo ON >NUL

==> prompt
```

Comment: it works when used: cmd /E:ON /V:ON /C for %%G in (01 02 03) do @echo !dir%%Ga! - but what to do, when I wants to run more commands in the FOR loop ? the ( more commands at more lines where also another %variables% are used to construct complex paths ) technique doesn't work...

Comment: Already updated: see `/K` switch; read _entire_ `cmd /?` again, please  @PeterMaly

Comment: thank You JosefZ
after some fiddling I created working script
I was returning back to My beginning (I was on the right way)
and the magic was simple - adding two lines at start of the script:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
setlocal EnableExtensions
 - one question more - where to publish My script to help others ?

Comment: @PeterMaly you could [edit and update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34046526/edit) or give your own answer. Please consider marking _most helpful answer_ as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%F in ('set dir 2^>nul') do echo %%G
```

where the `2^>nul` suppresses the error message generated if there are no variables set that start `dir`